# When advancing a skill can you spend multiple xp for a failed roll?

Tags: roll-for-shoes

In [Roll For Shoes](http://story-games.com/forums/discussion/11348/x) you gain a new related skill if you roll all 6's on your dice roll, however you can spend xp from failed rolls (you gain 1 xp per failure):

> XP can be used to change a die into a 6 for advancement purposes but
>   not for success purposes.

Does that mean if I roll a 3 and a 2 I can spend 2 xp to get 6 and 6 and a new skill?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### That is my understanding, yes.

As I see it, spending multiple XP for advancement is the primary method of acquiring higher-level skills at all.

It's the way I've played it, and it certainly makes the skills advance more quickly--which makes the game more interesting, because skill acquisition is one of the primary methods of establishing setting details and determining the nature of the plot (such as it may be).

Perhaps more significantly, in my experience the primary function of XP is to keep everyone relatively close to the same "power level." With the ability to spend multiple XP for advancement, those who fail regularly will wind up with higher skills later on--thus reducing the sting of failure *and* making them less likely to fail so regularly.

Comment: Makes sense to me; just clarifying page 57 of these highly complex rules ;)

Comment: Wow...I totally misread the rules and thought that XP was for the exact **opposite** thing it was for (succeeding, but not advancing) I am glad this has been clarified for me.